# 301 redirect of all files and subfolders to main url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a hacked site that has thousands of 404 errors now that I have fixed it. I want to redirect everything in the folders that were from the hack back to the home page. For example, this is one of the hacked urls:

http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/scategory/aqrqxjfo-x10001-zlggclj/whlhgxtx-y298119-bucavsa/

I am trying to do this via the .htaccess file. It is a wordpress website so I already have some standard rewrite rules. Basically I tried the following but it breaks the site with an internal server error:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^scategory/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^whosonline/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^admintools/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If I take out the following rewrite rules it works but of course it doesn't redirect:

```
 RewriteRule ^scategory/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^whosonline/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^admintools/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]]
```

Could someone help me with my rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `301` rules before default WP rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^scategory/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^whosonline/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^admintools/(.*)  http://www.truckeeriverrock.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This is because WP rule changes `REQUEST_URI` to `/index.php` hence your rules fail to match given patterns.

Comment: Awesome, works perfect, I new it was something like this that I was missing. Thank you!